# Changing the color of ListView items in a ListView

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Basically, I have two states which I need to maintain for `ListViewItem` :

1. Pressed
2. Selected

Also, I need to change the color of `ListViewItem` on runtime, like I would need to apply red or pink or green etc.

I searched around and found I need to do something with `ItemContainerStyle`, also as I need it to change dynamically I would have to switch between colors via code and not `XAML`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the pressed and selected colors, you will need to modify the ItemContainerStyle.  In Blend, right click on the ListView, then select Edit Additional Templates -> Edit Generated Item Container (ItemContainerStyle) -> Edit a Copy.  Use the States panel to update the Selected and Pressed states.  You will have to navigate to the appropriate element in the Document tree that controls the colors you want to change.

If you need to change the settings are runtime, you will need to databind the style properties to some sort of "ColorSettings" property.  that property needs to come from either the data you are binding the listview too (add a SelectedColor property, for example), or to some sort of master settings object.